# Data warehousing (ETL): Scheduled data migration from MySQL to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, etl

I've been assigned task of data warehousing for Reporting and data analysis. Let me first explain what we are going to do.

**Step 1**. Replicate production server `MySQL` database.

**Step 2**. `Scheduled ETL`: Read replicated database (`MySQL`) and push data to `PostgreSQL`.

Now I need your help on **Step 2.**

**Note:** I want `saveOrUpdate` functionality. If `id` is available then update it or save it. Data will be picked up based on `modified` date.

**So is there any tool available for `scheduled` data push in `PostgreSQL`?, Considering my requirements.**

If there ain't any tool available then which programming language I should use for ETL? And other pointers you can provide me to achieve this.

Asked same question https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/203460/data-warehousing-etl-scheduled-data-migration-from-mysql-to-postgresql on `dba.stackexchange.com` but I guess it has low userbase so posting it here.

Comment: Googling finds me the Pentaho tools.  https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Pentaho+Data+Integration+%28Kettle%29+Tutorial I'm not an expert, though.

Comment: I did Google but was not that satisfactory so asking experts.

Answer (score 0):

On aws you have [DMS](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/). I don't know if you can use it with external services but it's works pretty well.